# Kafka Consumer subscribes to topic but doesn't consume messages and doesn't appear in consumer group list

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api, publish-subscribe

A Kafka Consumer (org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.3.0) should consume messages from a topic with one partition.

The service logs the consumer subscription but it doesn't consume messages and doesn't appear in consumer group list using the [Official Apache Tools](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`.

```
2020-06-15 11:50:50.308 [main] INFO  o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=my-groupid] Subscribed to topic(s): my-topic
```

Service configuration should be OK because it works in pre-production environment.
The difference between the environments is that production has three hosts and pre-production just one and I'm sure that there aren't networking issues.

What might be the cause behind this?

Comment: Any good reason why you're not sharing your code?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous think it's unnecessary because I'm sure the code works. I'm looking for some higher level suggestions. What part of code should I share to enrich my question?

Comment: Is topic "healthy", i.e. it has ISR > `min.insync.replica`? Any diff in `acks` on producer side?

Comment: This log message is printed when you call `subscribe()`. It does not indicate the consumer is part of the group, is consuming or is even connected as you can call `subscribe()` without calling `poll()`! Please attach some code and/or the full client logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was zookeeper configuration. It was configured in 3 independent nodes handling 3 Kafka brokers and not in a distributed system.